# Manually initiated crash on Windows Server 2016 BSODs but hangs at 0%

Tags: windows-10, memory, bsod, crash, windows-server-2016

While testing any manually initiating crash on Windows Server 2016, I get a BSOD. It then says it is collecting data and will restart automatically. However, it gets stuck at 0%.

Configuration:
Processors - 48 cores. (2 sockets)
RAM: 128 GB.
HDD: Tested with 600 GB, 1.25 TB it fails.

Interestingly, when I tried with some other configuration - 20 cores and 8 GB RAM, it succeeds.

Pagefile is configured to be OS managed.

**NOTE: The Windows Server 2016 runs in a virtual environment.**

I have searched on the web for possible reasons but I found the configuration that I used follows almost all of those suggested ones (from Microsoft forum pages).

Via this post, I want some probable reasons (especially, being in a virtualized environment) to start for.

**Updated**
I am interested mostly in ***Complete Dumps***.

Comment: Are you taking a full, kernel or mini dump? Does kernel/mini work out of interest if say a full dump fails?

Comment: I am interested in Complete Dumps. Interestingly, in some cases, complete dump succeeds but the follow up kernel and minidump fails. Don't know the reason for this behavior.

Comment: try automatic/active dump and not complete to save space. Writing 128GB dump to disk may take some time

Comment: I agree. But for 128 GB RAM I waited for 5 mins. but it doesn't move past 0%. If I saw 1% then I could know that it is working.

Comment: try ActiveDump setting